# Lock password required after some time of not using it

Tags: security

Unlocking my phone every time gets a bit annoying, but I still want the phone to be locked for security purposes.

Is there a way for the phone to ask me for my passcode only if I haven't used the phone for longer than say 30 minutes?

This way if my phone is lost it will still have the password protection, and when I am using my phone in short spurts it won't force me to enter the password.

Nexus 6p
Android 7 Nougat

Comment: @beeshyams no it isn't rooted.  I updated my Q.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my solution as I didn't quite realise you are on Android 7. You can try this option and let me know if works .This **may work** is [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , easy to learn automation app ( *may work* since developer claims there could be issues due to Android implementation). **Trigger:** Empty Trigger ;**Action:** Screen Lock Off; **Constraints:** None. From the app *widget* . Select the widget, drop it on to your home screen and assign this macro to the widget. Click to manually enable / disable the macro

Answer (score 1):

All  of what you need can be done on Native android; No apps or root required. Go into your settings, Display, and Set 'Sleep' To 30 Minutes of inactivity.

Then, go into the Lock screen/security settings, and **untick** 'Power button instantly locks device'

Now, even though hitting the power button turns the screen off, it won't lock, and if you leave the phone to it, it will lock and turn off after 30 mins.

As Ethan Said, you can also adjust how long after the screen turning off the phone locks, then just disable lock on power button as before.

Answer (score 0):

With my android emulator I was able to prove that this is a native setting within Android. Assuming you have a password already (duh), go to settings-> Security -> screen lock settings (the gear) -> automatically lock. This is the setting that will determine how log after the phone is put to sleep, the password is enabled again.

However, this is only when the screen times out from being left on. When the screen is locked manually, the password will enable regardless. The only way to override this behavior is with rooted apps, and your device is not rooted.